# Communicating from Android service - broadcast or message?

Tags: android, service, communication

In my Android app, I have an `IntentService` which loads data periodically from a web service. I want this service to tell the main user interface when it starts and when it finishes, so that the UI fragment can say when an update is in progress, when the last update took place and so forth.

There would seem to be two ways of doing this:

- Use a broadcast (via [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)).
- Post a [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) from the `IntentService`, and implement a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in the UI fragment to update the UI.

What are the pros and cons of these two methods? - and which would be better for my case?

Thanks!

Comment: Better would a solution that works. You may also use an event bus like Otto or GreenRobot. Or a model class (injected or inside `Application` subclass) + observer pattern that is accessible from `Activity` and `Service`: in service you put data and registered activity is notified. I suggest trying the one that feels the simplest for you.

Comment: There are more options than those two. I'd use a third-party event bus, like Otto or greenrobot's EventBus, assuming that the event only needs to be handled if the UI exists. If I need to update the UI *or* raise a `Notification`, that calls for an ordered broadcast.